# Is it possible to allow my bitcoin core node to connect remotely to sparrow but also locally?

Tags: bitcoin-core, sparrow-wallet

I've changed the config file to connect my Sparrow wallet to the node, but when I do that, the ability to connect a different Sparrow wallet locally is gone. Is there a way to allow both?